# how to register the container to landscape?

Tags: landscape

I have successfully deployed the landscape on-premises and can register the Ubuntu client to it.

but have no idea about how to register the container to landscape

does anyone have any ideas?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the answer.

it's lxd runs ubuntu docker...very easy

please ignore this question.

Thanks